# singular matrix statement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A and B are square matrices of the same order.  for every singular A, there exists B that is different than zero that satisfies the equation $A^2B=A^5B$.

prove or disprove the statement.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What is your question? What work have you done on this so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding matrix $B$ is not zero matrix where $AB= 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243160/finding-matrix-b-is-not-zero-matrix-where-ab-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is singular, then there is a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Av=0$. Let $B$ be the matrix whose columns are all copies of $v$ (note that $B$ is nonzero since $v$ is nonzero). Then $AB=0$, so $A^2B=0$ and $A^5B=0$ and thus $A^2B=A^5B$.

If $A$ is nonsingular, then $A^2B=A^5B$ iff $B = A^3B$, and this can only happen if each row of $B$ is a eigenvector of $A^3$ with eigenvalue $1$. Therefore such $B$ exist only when $A$ has an eigenvalue of $1$, $e^{-2\pi i/3}$ or $e^{2\pi i /3}$.

Answer (score 0):

If A is symmetric, take B as the Drazin inverse of A.
The drazin inverse of symmetric matrices always exits and it is the only matrix that satisfies:

AD=DA,
ADA=A,
DAD=D

See Cline´s book or Meyer'book.